# .htaccess redirect rules are not executed in order

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /old/path/ https://www.newdomain.com/new/
# and a lot of other redirects

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I placed this in the old domain's root directory.

I expect that when I enter `https://www.olddomain.com/old/path/` the rule `Redirect 301 /old/path/ https://www.newdomain.com/new/` is fired first and so the new URL would be `https://www.newdomain.com/new/`.

Instead it gets redirected to `https://www.newdomain.com/old/path/`.

If I remove the last redirect, everything works like expected, so the new URL is `https://www.newdomain.com/new/`. But I need the last redirect because I want also the subpages redirected to the new domain for which I didn't specifically set a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your rules, please check:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^old\/path\/$ https://www.newdomain.com/new/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.newdomain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```